Error MSB6006: "mtouch" exited with code 1. (MSB6006)
In my Visual Studio For Mac, I can run the project in simulator its building , but while archiving the app for publishing i am getting the error

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3):
Error MSB6006: "mtouch" exited with code 1. (MSB6006) ,

Now what I need to do ?
while archiving the app for publishing
